# Optimization of Hyperparameter in a Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, conv-neural-network, hyperparameters

I am facing a problem regarding **Optimization of Hyperparameters** in a Convolutional Neural Network for the analysis of text data. First, I will explain my process so far: 
With the help of various excellent Blog-Posts I was able to build a CNN that works for my project. In my project I am trying to predict the VIX and S&P 500 with the help of the FOMC meeting statements. So basically I habe text data on the one hand and financial data (returns) on the other hand. After preprocessing and applying Googles Word2Vec pre-trained Word-Embeddings I built the following Convolutional Network:

```py
def ConvNet(embeddings, max_sequence_length, num_words, embedding_dim, trainable=False, extra_conv=True,
            lr=0.001, dropout=0.5):
    embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                                embedding_dim,
                                weights=[embeddings],
                                input_length=max_sequence_length,
                                trainable=trainable)

    sequence_input = Input(shape=(max_sequence_length,), dtype='int32')
    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)

    convs = []
    filter_sizes = [3, 4, 5]

    for filter_size in filter_sizes:
        l_conv = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=filter_size, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
        l_pool = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3)(l_conv)
        convs.append(l_pool)

    l_merge = concatenate([convs[0], convs[1], convs[2]], axis=1)

    # add a 1D convnet with global maxpooling, instead of Yoon Kim model
    conv = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
    pool = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3)(conv)

    if extra_conv == True:
        x = Dropout(dropout)(l_merge)
    else:
        # Original Yoon Kim model
        x = Dropout(dropout)(pool)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    preds = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)

    model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
    sgd = SGD(learning_rate = lr, momentum= 0.8)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                  optimizer= sgd,
                  metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
    model.summary()
    return model

model = ConvNet(train_embedding_weights, MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, len(train_word_index)+1, EMBEDDING_DIM, False)

#define callbacks
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.01, patience=4, verbose=1)
callbacks_list = [early_stopping]

hist = model.fit(x_train, y_tr, epochs=5, batch_size=33, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

My model architecture looks like this:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 1086)         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)         (None, 1086, 300)    532500      input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)               (None, 1084, 128)    115328      embedding_1[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)               (None, 1083, 128)    153728      embedding_1[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

conv1d_3 (Conv1D)               (None, 1082, 128)    192128      embedding_1[0][0]                


__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 361, 128)     0           conv1d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 361, 128)     0           conv1d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_3 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 360, 128)     0           conv1d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 1082, 128)    0           max_pooling1d_1[0][0]            
                                                                 max_pooling1d_2[0][0]            
                                                                 max_pooling1d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 1082, 128)    0           concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 138496)       0           dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 128)          17727616    flatten_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            129         dense_3[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 18,721,429
Trainable params: 18,188,929
Non-trainable params: 532,500
```

Model architecture: 
[image]

So, now I am facing the next big problem, and I am really running out of ideas how to solve is: **Optimization of hyperparameters**

So my specific question is, how to perform the Optimization of hyperparameters?

My search code is:

```
from hyperopt import fmin, hp, tpe, space_eval, Trials

def train_and_score(args):
    # Train the model the fixed params plus the optimization args.
    # Note that this method should return the final History object.
    test = ConvNet(embeddings=train_embedding_weights, max_sequence_length= MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                    num_words=len(train_word_index)+1, embedding_dim= EMBEDDING_DIM,
                   trainable=False, extra_conv=True,
                   lr=args['lr'], dropout=args['dropout'])
    # Unpack and return the last validation loss from the history.
    return test['val_loss'][-1]

# Define the space to optimize over.
space = {
    'lr': hp.loguniform('lr', np.log(0.01), np.log(0.1)),
    'dropout': hp.uniform('dropout', 0, 0.5)
}

# Minimize the training score over the space.
trials = Trials()
best = fmin(fn=train_and_score,
             space=space,
             trials=trials,
             algo=tpe.suggest,
             max_evals=100)

# Print details about the best results and hyperparameters.
print(best)
print(space_eval(space, best))
```

The specific error message is:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
  0%|          | 0/100 [00:00<?, ?trial/s, best loss=?]
job exception: 'Model' object is not subscriptable

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lukaskoston/Desktop/MasterarbeitFOMCAnalysis/07_Regression/CNN regression neu.py", line 262, in <module>
    max_evals=100)
  File "/Users/lukaskoston/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 482, in fmin
    show_progressbar=show_progressbar,
  File "/Users/lukaskoston/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 686, in fmin
    show_progressbar=show_progressbar,
  File "/Users/lukaskoston/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 509, in fmin
    rval.exhaust()
  File "/Users/lukaskoston/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 330, in exhaust
    self.run(self.max_evals - n_done, block_until_done=self.asynchronous)
  File "/Users/lukaskoston/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 286, in run
    self.serial_evaluate()
  File "/Users/lukaskoston/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 165, in serial_evaluate
    result = self.domain.evaluate(spec, ctrl)
  File "/Users/lukaskoston/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 894, in evaluate
    rval = self.fn(pyll_rval)
  File "/Users/lukaskoston/Desktop/MasterarbeitFOMCAnalysis/07_Regression/CNN regression neu.py", line 248, in train_and_score
    return hist['val_loss'][-1]
TypeError: 'Model' object is not subscriptable
```

Thanks in advance, 
Lukas

Comment: Where is your training/parameter search code?  It's unclear to me how this error is related to hyperparameter optimization

Comment: I added it, Thanks, I think now it should be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you're getting is because you're trying to directly subset a model which is not directly subsettable like a list or a dictionary.

Your `ConvNet` function defines and compiles a model but it does not train it or evaluate it.  You'll need to run `model.fit()` to train it and store the output of the training history like you did in the first script you posted `hist = model.fit(...)`. You can then change the return statement of `train_and_score` to something like `return hist.history['val_loss'][-1]`.

I would start by taking your first bit of training code

```
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.01, patience=4, verbose=1)
callbacks_list = [early_stopping]

hist = model.fit(x_train, y_tr, epochs=5, batch_size=33, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

and add it to your `train_and_score` function after the model definition. And then change the return statement.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, I really appreciate that! I am really new to Python and Neural Networks, I don't get exactly what I have to change.. I don't know if that's too much to ask, but would you be so kind and show me what I have to change in the code?

Comment: I added a bit more explanation. In order to test or score a model, you must first train it. You already seem to know how to use `*.fit`, you just need to use that code to train your model during every call of `test_and_score`. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes indeed it helped, It is running now. I just don't unterstand, why I should change the return statement of train_and_score to something like return hist.history['val_loss'][-1] ? Could you explain that further? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What you had originally `test['val_loss'][-1]` is attempting to do a dictionary-like hash lookup in the object 'test' of the string 'val_loss'.  `test` is an object of type `tf.keras.Model` and does not have data stored in a way that can be accessed like that.  The error you received said it like this: `TypeError: 'Model' object is not subscriptable`.  On the other hand, the output of `model.fit()` is a record of training loss values and metrics.

Comment: look at `returns` here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit

Comment: @LukasKoston if everything is good, you can accept the answer

Comment: I have one more additional question... Do you have any idea how I could add convolutional Layer to my ConvNet function? I added the picture of my architecture right now, but I would like to add a Convolutional Layer and Max Pooling ? Thanks in advance, Lukas

Comment: @LukasKoston Your `ConvNet` function already does this.  You can add more by adding more filter parameters to the filter list or by just manually adding more layers.  You need to be aware of shapes as you do this though.

Comment: I opened and further question regarding my CNN, maybe you can help me there as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064068/save-optimization-of-hyperparameter-in-a-convolutional-neural-net