# Save Optimization of Hyperparameter in a Convolutional Neural Net

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, conv-neural-network, hyperparameters

I am facing a problem regarding saving the training process of the hyperparameter in my Convolutional Neural Net. I have read couple of blog posts, but somehow I am unable to do that.

I have the following code:

```
def ConvNet(embeddings, max_sequence_length, num_words, embedding_dim, trainable=False, extra_conv=True,
            lr=0.0001, dropout=0.7, filters = 128, momentum = 0.8, units = 32, pool_size = 3):
    embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                                embedding_dim,
                                weights=[embeddings],
                                input_length=max_sequence_length,
                                trainable=trainable)

    sequence_input = Input(shape=(max_sequence_length,), dtype='int32')
    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
    convs = []
    filter_sizes = [3, 4, 5]
    for filter_size in filter_sizes:
        l_conv = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=filter_size, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
        l_pool = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size)(l_conv)
        l_conv2 = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(l_pool)
        l_pool2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size)(l_conv2)

        convs.append(l_pool2)

    l_merge = concatenate(convs, axis=1)

    # add a 1D convnet with global maxpooling, instead of Yoon Kim model
    conv = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
    pool = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size)(conv)

    if extra_conv == True:
        x = Dropout(dropout)(l_merge)
    else:
        # Original Yoon Kim model
        x = Dropout(dropout)(pool)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(units = units, activation='relu')(x)
    preds = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)

    model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
    sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate = lr, momentum= momentum)
    model.compile(loss= r_square_loss,
                  optimizer= sgd,
                  metrics=['mean_squared_error', rmse, r_square])

    model.summary()
    return model
```

I am optimizing the hyper parameter with the following function:

```
from hyperopt import fmin, hp, tpe, space_eval, Trials

def train_and_score(args):
    # Train the model the fixed params plus the optimization args.
    # Note that this method should return the final History object.
    model = ConvNet(embeddings=train_embedding_weights, max_sequence_length= MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                    num_words=len(train_word_index)+1, embedding_dim= EMBEDDING_DIM,
                   trainable=False, extra_conv=True,
                   lr=args['lr'], dropout=args['dropout'], filters=args['filters'],
                    momentum= args['momentum'], units = args['units'])
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='mean_squared_error', patience=40, verbose=1, mode='auto')

    hist = model.fit(x_train, y_tr, epochs=args['epochs'], batch_size=args['batch_size'], validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True,
                     callbacks=[early_stopping])

    #Unpack and return the last validation loss from the history.
    return hist.history['val_loss'][-1]

 #Define the space to optimize over.
space = {
    'lr': hp.choice('lr', [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]),
    'dropout': hp.choice('dropout', [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]),
    'filters': hp.choice('filters', [32, 64, 128, 256]),
    'pool_size': hp.choice('pool_size', [2, 3]),
    'momentum': hp.choice('momentum', [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]),
    'units': hp.choice('units', [32, 64, 128, 256]),
    'epochs': hp.choice('epochs', [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]),
    'batch_size': hp.choice('batch_size', [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80])
}

# Minimize the training score over the space.
trials = Trials()
best = fmin(fn=train_and_score,
            space=space,
            trials=trials,
            max_evals = 10,
            algo=tpe.suggest)

# Print details about the best results and hyperparameters.
print(best)
print(space_eval(space, best))
```

As of now, I have max_evals equal to 10, to see if everything works. For the actual training process I would like to set it to 500 and let it run for one day... **So here is my question:** How do I save the training process? I think it would be enough just to save the best one in a file or something, as this is a university project and I have to hand in a "proof" that I trained the CNN.

**Additional question:** As of now, after the 10 evaluations, I am taking the best parameters and fill it manually into the above provided code to predict the test set and calculate some statistical numbers like mse, r-square etc.

```
model = ConvNet(train_embedding_weights, MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, len(train_word_index)+1, EMBEDDING_DIM,
                trainable=False, extra_conv=True,
                lr=0.0001, dropout=0.6, filters= 128,
                momentum= 0.8, units = 32, pool_size = 2)

#define callbacks
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='mean_squared_error', patience=40, verbose=1, mode='auto')

hist = model.fit(x_train, y_tr, epochs=30, batch_size=20, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=False, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

**My dream would be to set the max_eval to 500 and that the result ist stored in an output file (just the best hyper parameter combination is enough) and that afterwards the obtained best hyper parameter are automatically taken to calculate x test and the statistical numbers mse, r-square etc.**

Can anyone please help? I am stuck here for many, many, many hours.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the exact answer to that question, however there is [here](https://medium.com/vooban-ai/hyperopt-tutorial-for-optimizing-neural-networks-hyperparameters-e3102814b919) a "trick" that might do it.

It proposes to print the content of every trial tested, at the end of the code. Maybe you can save the "trials" object as well in a pickle or something, so that you can parse and check for yourself later.
I do have the exact same question and i'm very very suprise that there is no "easy" solution as with the keras callbacks to save the best trained model.

I also suggest you to change the title of your questiopn, adding at least "Hyperopt", "callbacks" and "saving model" key words. With more attention maybe our question will be answered :)